# Bootstrap navbar incorrectly rendering links as seperate lines in mobile view (Ruby on Rails app) - How to Fix?

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

In my Ruby on Rails app, everything renders fine on the desktop view but when I visit the site from my iPhone the navbar is rendering way too big:

http://i.imgur.com/SWcklWw.png

As you can see in the picture, the "Home" and "Log in" buttons are seperate lines in the navbar when they should be on one line together, the same on as the logo to the left side.

How can I fix this to look much better on the mobile version of the site...? Here's the code for the header as well if it might help... I replaced the site's name just because I don't want people visiting it until it's production-quality.

```
<header class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container">
        <%= link_to "(site name)", root_path, id: "logo" %> 
        <nav>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
                <li>
                  <%= link_to root_path do %>
                  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span>&nbsp;Home
                  <% end %>
                </li>
                <% if logged_in? %>
                    <li>
                        <%= link_to new_listing_path do %>
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>&nbsp;New Listing
                        <% end %>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <%= link_to users_path do%>
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-list"></span>&nbsp;Users
                        <% end %>
                    </li> 
                    <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
              Account <b class="caret"></b>
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li>
                                <%= link_to current_user do %>
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>&nbsp;Profile
                                <% end %>
                                </li> 
                            <li>
                                <%= link_to edit_user_path(current_user) do %>
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span>&nbsp;Settings
                                <% end %>
                            </li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>
                            <li>
                                <%= link_to logout_path, method: "delete" do %>
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></span>&nbsp;Log out
                                <% end %>
                            </li>
                        </ul>       
                    </li>
                <% else %>
                    <li>
                        <%= link_to login_path do %>
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span>&nbsp;Log in
                        <% end %>
                    </li>
                <% end %>
            </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Check your navbar structure again. Look at examples here http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar
Basically your's looks wrong.

Comment: I was examining the Examples and comparing it to my own but I still don't understand why the links are being placed on seperate lines rather than side-by-side... Is it because I'm using "pull-right"?

Comment: check the answer. gl:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go.

[image]
[image]

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">"(site name)"</a>
    </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar">  
       <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
         <li>
           <%= link_to root_path do %>
           <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span>&nbsp;Home
           <% end %>
         </li>
                 <% if logged_in? %>        
         <li>
             <%= link_to new_listing_path do %>
             <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>&nbsp;New Listing
             <% end %>
         </li>
            <li>
                <%= link_to users_path do%>
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-list"></span>&nbsp;Users
                <% end %>
            </li>                           
                 <li class="dropdown">
           <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Account</a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
             <li>
                 <%= link_to current_user do %>
                 <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>&nbsp;Profile
                 <% end %>
                 </li>
             <li>
                 <%= link_to edit_user_path(current_user) do %>
                 <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span>&nbsp;Settings
                 <% end %>
             </li>
             <li class="divider"></li>
             <li>
                 <%= link_to logout_path, method: :delete do %>
                 <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></span>&nbsp;Log out
                 <% end %>
             </li>
            </ul>
         </li>

                 <% else %>
         <li>
             <%= link_to login_path do %>
             <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span>&nbsp;Log in
             <% end %>
         </li>
                 <% end %>
      </ul>
        </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```